# Cannot set custom ROS_HOME in launch file

Tags: newtags

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I want to have a current directory for my node different than ~/.ros, so that when I create files in my node providing only local file name, they are saved relevant to my given $ROS_HOME. I tried the following launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
   <env name="ROS_HOME" value="/home/alex" />
   <node name="test" type="test.py" pkg="simple_pcl" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

But the file I am creating still appears in ~/.ros.
Here is the node source:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system('touch test_file')
```

I also tried setting ROS_HOME inside node entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <node name="test" type="test.py" pkg="simple_pcl" output="screen">
    <env name="ROS_HOME" value="/home/alex" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

also without success. What do you think is the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50970/cannot-set-custom-ros_home-in-launch-file/) by [Alexey Ozhigov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3834/alexey-ozhigov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [docs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_HOME) it sets the location where ROS tools write data.  I don't believe it changes the current working directory where your program is launched. All the core ROS tools evaluate for the existance of ROS_HOME and default to ~/.ros if it is not set.  If your program reads ROS_HOME inside it's run, you can reproduce the same policy.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1